# Почему здесь вылетает ошибка?

Tags: javascript, деструктурирующее-присваивание, объекты

Почему я не могу св-ва объекта `dinner` присвоить таким образом св-вам объекта `obj`?

```
let dinner = {
  drink: 'cola', 
  food: 'cake'
};

let obj = {};
{obj.one, obj.two} = dinner;
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring-assignment#destrukturizatsiya-obekta

Comment: @soledar10, и что должна была показать эта ссылка?

Comment: @Grundy по этой ссылке есть описание ошибки.  ```Чтобы показать, что это не блок кода, мы можем заключить выражение в скобки (...):```.

Comment: @soledar10, стоило это в текст ссылки вставить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблем в данном случае несколько:

1. Нет сопоставления свойств в шаблоне с источником. `{obj.one, obj.two}` данный шаблон не указывает каким именно способом сопоставлять данные с переменными. Для решения достаточно указать конкретные поля: `{ drink: obj.one, food: obj.two }`
2. Неоднозначность использования фигурных скобок, в данном случае они расцениваются не как литерал объекта, либо шаблон для сопоставления, а как блок кода. Для исправления достаточно взять все выражение в скобки. `({...} = source)`

Если исправить недочеты, код начинает работать:

```js
let dinner = {
  drink: 'cola',
  food: 'cake'
};

let obj = {};

({
  drink: obj.one,
  food: obj.two
} = dinner);

console.log(obj)
```

Для избегания неоднозначности можно воспользоваться деструктуризацией массива

```js
let dinner = {
  drink: 'cola',
  food: 'cake'
};

let obj = {};

[obj.one, obj.two] = [dinner.drink, dinner.food];

console.log(obj);
```